# Table records to convert into JSON file in unix with jq

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, json

I have table on a Linux machine which has a number of records; I am running a query to get:

```
select * from TABNAME_XYZ


CID CN    XY     NAT   UIC    DATE        Region
12  2123  120.9  29.0  100.0  2018-06-08  JAIPUR
13  0987  78.9   100.3 28.8   2020-12-09  DELHI
```

I want to write a shell script that convert its output to JSON, but I really don't know where to begin or what to do. The JSON must be like this:

```
{"CID":"12","CN":"2123","DATA":{"XY":120.9,"NAT":29.0,"UIC":100.0,"Date":"2018-06-08","REGION":"JAIPUR"}},
{"CID":"13","CN":"0987","DATA":{"XY":78.9,"NAT":100.3,"UIC":28.8,"Date":"2020-12-09","REGION":"DELHI"}}
```

I already have `jq` on my system.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: i can query the same table on oracle sql developer but need to generate this query via shell script only;; i can also run sql statement on unix command line but it gives general output without any line..it only contain the blank spaces between the records

Comment: does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/23560996/4023950?

Comment: If you REALLY want to convert `DATE` to `Date` and `Region` to `REGION` then [edit] your question to explain the logic around which fields to select to change the case of. If you don't really want that then [edit] your question to fix your example.

Comment: Are you sure that `,` should be present at the end of the first row of expected output? That doesn't appear to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the fields are always in the given order, that there is a header line on the first line of input, and that multiple space characters delimit fields, you may compress the runs of consecutive spaces with `tr` and parse the data with `jq`.

```bsh
database-client-command |
tr -s ' ' |
jq -c -Rn '
        input  | split(" ") as $head |
        inputs | split(" ") |
                to_entries |
                        map(.key = $head[.key]) |
                        [ .[:2][], { key: "DATA", value: (.[2:] | from_entries) } ] |
                from_entries'
```

The `jq` expression reads the raw data from `tr` as separate lines.

The first line is split into the headers and stored into an array in `$head`.

We split the remaining lines into arrays as we did with the header.  The `to_entries` filter converts each array into "entry form" (collections of objects with `key` and `value` keys), and the `map()` replaces the numerical array indexes with the headers from `$head` as keys.

After the `map()`, the filter rearranges the array the third element on are moved down into a separate `DATA` sub-object and converted back from "entry form".

When done with the keys and data rearrangement, the `from_entries` filter returns the array from the "entry form".

The output of the script would be a set of JSON objects, and  given the data in your question, these would look as follows.

```json
{"CID":"12","CN":"2123","DATA":{"XY":"120.9","NAT":"29.0","UIC":"100.0","DATE":"2018-06-08","Region":"JAIPUR"}}
{"CID":"13","CN":"0987","DATA":{"XY":"78.9","NAT":"100.3","UIC":"28.8","DATE":"2020-12-09","Region":"DELHI"}}
```

If you want to change `Region` into `REGION` and `DATE` into `Date`, then consider doing this as you query the database or as a post-processing step.

Note that your expected result is not valid JSON due to the trailing comma on the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't REALLY want to convert `DATE` to `Date` and `Region` to `REGION` (if you do it's an easy tweak once you explain the logic for selecting which tags to change) and that you really do want a `,` at the end of every output line except the last (again, an easy tweak if you don't), then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    split($0,tags)
    next
}
{
    printf "%s{%s,%s,\"DATA\":{", sep, fmt(1), fmt(2)
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", fmt(i), (i<NF ? "," : "}}")
    }
    sep = ",\n"
}
END {
    print ""
}
function fmt(fldNr,     tag, val) {
    tag = tags[fldNr]
    val = $fldNr
    gsub(/"/,"\\\"",val)
    return sprintf("\"%s\":\"%s\"", tag, val)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{"CID":"12","CN":"2123","DATA":{"XY":"120.9","NAT":"29.0","UIC":"100.0","DATE":"2018-06-08","Region":"JAIPUR"}},
{"CID":"13","CN":"0987","DATA":{"XY":"78.9","NAT":"100.3","UIC":"28.8","DATE":"2020-12-09","Region":"DELHI"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Save the following as `foo.awk`:

```
{
  if(NR==1){
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      head[i]=$i
    }
  }
  else{
    printf "{\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\",\"DATA\":{\"%s\":%s,\"%s\":%s,\"%s\":%s,\"%s\":\"%s\",\"%s\":\"%s\"}}\n", head[1],$1,head[2],$2,head[3],$3,head[4],$4,head[5],$5,head[6],$6,head[7],$7;

  }
}
```

And then:

```
$ cat file |  awk -f foo.awk
{"CID":"12","CN":"2123","DATA":{"XY":120.9,"NAT":29.0,"UIC":100.0,"DATE":"2018-06-08","Region":"JAIPUR"}}
{"CID":"13","CN":"0987","DATA":{"XY":78.9,"NAT":100.3,"UIC":28.8,"DATE":"2020-12-09","Region":"DELHI"}}
```

Here, I have saved the output of your `select` command in the file `file`. In your case, you would use whatever command line client your database has. for instance, with mySQL, you would:

```
mysql -e 'select * from TABNAME_XYZ' | awk -f foo.awk
```

Comment: but you still need to care about fields containing double quotes to escape them too, simple `gsub(/"/,"\\"")` might do that.

Comment: It would be better to let the database output JSON. Many database engines can do this.  I have no clue about Oracle.

Comment: @they Oracle can according to the SO link that αғsнιη left in a comment: [Return results of a sql query as JSON in oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23560996). But it looks like something needs to be installed and the OP requested a shell solution.